# Upgrad Ubuntu-14-04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I understand that Ubuntu allows of upgrading 14.04 to 16. I run software updater it indicates that there is a new version, I click upgrade a couple of steps work then I get an error dialog box with the following messages

> W:Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/source/Sources
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] , W:Failed to fetch

So question, is this feasible/allowed as a an upgrade path? I would like upgrade and not a new install as I have chef and docker lot of configuration and data that I need to preserve.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 is allowed, but you must make sure you update 14.04 to the lastest code in the repo before starting the 16.04 upgrade.

Comment: Those messages indicate that you have added 14.10 (not 14.04) repositories to your system. There is NOT a supported upgrade path from 14.10 to 16.04 - the recommended method is to backup your data and then do a clean-install.

Comment: Sir I have done nothing only running updater  and followed instructions, not sure what do youy mean by "you have added 14.10". How can I get rid of this 14.10?

Comment: OK, can you tell me how can I remove those 14.10 repos please? Thanks